# How do prove a matrix statement

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

The problem is pretty simple conceptually but I am not sure how to write proofs out for matrixes.[image]

Comment: What do the vertical strokes bracketing $A$ mean here?  I'm tempted to assume you are asking about the determinant of $A$, but your use of an image and few words to explain the problem makes me unsure.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't think about it. The vertical strokes mean the determinant of some matrix A.

Comment: The key here is the property of a matrix product and the determinant.  So you can proceed to show $|A|$ satisfies a polynomial equation whose roots are $0$ and $1$ exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Theorem:** $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$

It follows from this that if $A^2=A$, then $$\det(A)^2=\det(A)\det(A)=\det(AA)=\det(A^2)=\det(A)$$ so $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=1$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how it applies exactly to the theorem though because the det(A)^2 corresponds well to the right hand side but the left hand side would only be the det(A) which does not have two values being multiplied.

Comment: Does my edit make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, very clear, thank you!